# On dit je suis d'accord pour/de patienter?

Tags: expressions, de

Quelqu'un m'a posé cette question:

"Etes-vous d'accord pour patienter?"

Je voudrais répondre par oui. Mais je ne suis pas sûr comment formuler la réponse. Quelle réponse est correcte:

"Oui je suis d'accord pour patienter" ou "Oui, je suis d'accord de patienter" ?

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: Le plus correct «… de patienter pour …» et pour élargir l’utilisation du verbe *patienter* et tenir compte des contextes, vous pourrez les retrouver dans les livres sélectionnés par : *de patienter pour,pour patienter,de patienter* -> https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pour%20patienter%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On dit « **d'accord pour** [faire quelque chose] » quand on accepte de faire quelque chose.

Le [*Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française* de Jean Girodet](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KOINHRkfU_oC&pg=PA257&dq=%22d%27+accord+de%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieoeHdh7noAhVPxYUKHWBSBdQ4ChDoAQhNMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22d'%20accord%20de%22&f=false) énonce que « Le tour *être d'accord de* (suivi de l'infinitif) n'est pas incorrect, mais seulement un peu archaïque ». Pour ma part, je ne le considère pas comme correct au 21<sup>e</sup> siècle. [« D'accord pour » domine largement depuis le milieu du 19<sup>e</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%27accord+pour%2C+d%27accord+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%27%20accord%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%27%20accord%20de%3B%2Cc0). Dans les textes modernes, on ne trouve la suite de mots « d'accord de » que quand le nom « accord » se trouve être introduit par l'article ou la préposition « de », et pas avec l'expression figée « d'accord ».

« D'accord » peut aussi être suivi d'autres prépositions. On est « **d'accord avec** quelqu'un ». On peut être « d'accord sur une idée » ou « d'accord avec une idée » suivant les cas : en général, on est d'accord avec un point de vue et d'accord sur un domaine de discussion, mais le choix peut être plus subtil.

Comment: Pour compléter ta réponse, une recherche google "vous êtes d'accord de" et "est d'accord de" donne des résultats positifs et contemporains tirés de documents suisses avant tout et belges aussi.  Ce tour classicisant et recherché en français de France est peut-être à l'heure actuelle un helvétisme voire un belgicisme.  Sinon, j'ai du mal à comprendre le passage suivant de ta réponse : "Dans les textes modernes, on ne trouve la suite de mots « d'accord de » que quand le nom « accord » se trouve être introduit par l'article ou la préposition « de », et pas avec l'expression figée « d'accord »".